# private set in deserialize json doens't set correctly

Tags: c#, class, domain-driven-design, json-deserialization, private-members

I have this class as you see :

```
public class UserScope
    {
        public List<Guid> testCenterIds { get; private set; }
        public List<Guid> roleIds { get; private set; }
        public List<int> townCodes { get; private set; }
        public List<int> CityCodes { get; private set; }
        public List<int> provinceCodes { get; private set; }
        public List<string> provinceCodes2 { get; private set; }

        public UserScope(List<Guid> testCenterIds, List<Guid> roleIds, List<int> townIds, List<int> cityIds, List<int> provinceIds, List<string> provinceIds2)
        {
            this.testCenterIds = testCenterIds;
            this.roleIds = roleIds;
            this.townCodes = townIds;
            this.CityCodes = cityIds;
            this.provinceCodes = provinceIds;
            this.provinceCodes2 = provinceIds2;
        }
    }
```

When I want to convert my json to model as you can see :

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        var uc = new UserScope(
   new List<Guid> { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() },
      new List<Guid> { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() },
      new List<int> { 12126 },
      new List<int> { 12122 },
      new List<int> { 12312, 13479 }, new List<string> { "12312", "13479" }

  );
        var jsons = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(uc);

        var jsond = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserScope>(jsons);
    }
```

JsonConvert can't convert `townCodes ,CityCodes,provinceCodes  ,provinceCodes2`  and initializes them,In final `townCodes ,CityCodes,provinceCodes  ,provinceCodes2` are null.But `testCenterIds,roleIds` work fine.why?

Comment: Side note: The .Net naming conventions clearly states using [PascalCase for public members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `UserScope` only have one constructor which accepts certain arguments (no default constructor with no arguments), and no properties are marked with `JsonProperty`, so JSON.NET assumes it needs to call that constructor to create an instance. It then matches keys from json string with names of arguments of that constructor. `testCenterIds` and `roleIds` names do match said keys, while other argument names do not, so JSON.NET pass nulls there instead. If you rename constructor arguments like this:

```
public UserScope(List<Guid> testCenterIds, List<Guid> roleIds, List<int> townCodes, List<int> cityCodes, List<int> provinceCodes, List<string> provinceCodes2)
{
    this.testCenterIds = testCenterIds;
    this.roleIds = roleIds;
    this.townCodes = townCodes;
    this.CityCodes = cityCodes;
    this.provinceCodes = provinceCodes;
    this.provinceCodes2 = provinceCodes2;
}
```

Then they all will be populated. Alternatively you can mark all properties with `JsonProperty` attribute (good to always do that if possible and suitable) as mentioned in answer linked in comments.